# How to find the whole word with re.findall?

Tags: python, findall

this is my code:

```
str_list = 'Hallo Welt Halloer' 
conversations_counter = len(re.findall("Hallo", str_list))
print(conversations_counter)
```

The result is 2!
But I just want to have a match for the whole word 'Hallo'. The word 'Hallo' in the word 'Halloer' should not be counted.

Hallo = Hallo -> 1
Halloer <> Hallo -> 0

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the requirement.  If you already know you are looking for the word `Hallo`, which has 5 characters, then why do you even need this script?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I belies they are looking to count the occurrences of the word rather than the string which they are counting now. Not the number of characters in the word/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'word boundary' to your regex:

```
Hallo\b
```

Don't forget to set the regex using `r`, not as string:

```py
import re

str_list = 'Hallo Welt Halloer' 
conversations_counter = len(re.findall(r"Hallo\b", str_list))
print(conversations_counter) # 1
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCgJBDAX7/Ypwze2C2Fjb@wc2wnGeEQMxWd5Gwa9fjwM7uylmpn7i4XboXZ7VEQROqQUmlRZ0pPE0qzqdWYM2ZIyUFrc3o80hbm1a/GXBWG1ly@D9Xey2uhnDllyuw45@z1JShVjkv4/S@xc)

Comment: You should probably have word boundaries on _both_ sides of the word, i.e. use `\bHallo\b`.